# Like counter in array list keep returning 0

Tags: java, sql, arraylist

I try to do the like counter for forum threads. This is my code:

When like button is on click, it will insert the value into database.

```
public void submitLike(ActionEvent e) {
    int count = 0;
    int newCount = count + 1;
    eForumLikeDislike amount = new eForumLikeDislike(userName,topicId,newCount);
    amount.likeCounter();
}
```

The `SQL statement` which I insert like when it is on click.

```
 public void SetUpLikeAmount() {
    int likes = 0;
    ArrayList <Integer> likeArray = new ArrayList <Integer>();
    for (int count = 0; count < likeArray.size();count++){
    // Set Up Database Source
    db.setUp("IT Innovation Project");
    String sql = "Select likeDislike_likes from forumLikeDislike WHERE topic_id = "
            + topicId + "";
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    // Call readRequest to get the result
    resultSet = db.readRequest(sql);
    try {
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            likeArray.add(Integer.parseInt(resultSet.getString("likeDislike_likes")));
        }
        resultSet.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    likes += likeArray.get(count);
    }
    jLabel_like.setText(Integer.toString(likes));
}
```

The method which I try to display the total likes of certain thread.

```
public void SetUpLikeAmount() {
    int likes = 0;
    ArrayList <Integer> likeArray = new ArrayList <Integer>();
    for (int count = 0; count < likeArray.size();count++) {
        // Set Up Database Source
        db.setUp("IT Innovation Project");
        String sql = "Select likeDislike_likes from forumLikeDislike WHERE topic_id = "
                     + topicId + "";
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        // Call readRequest to get the result
        resultSet = db.readRequest(sql);
        try {
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                likes = Integer.parseInt(resultSet.getString("likeDislike_likes"));
                likes += likeArray.get(count);
            }
            resultSet.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
    jLabel_like.setText(Integer.toString(likes));
}
```

However, the amount keep returning me 0. Is there something wrong? How can I fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to change your database design, do so.  Specifically, drop the field likeDislike_likes from table forumLikeDislike.

Once you have done that (or even if you don't), you can replace this query,

```
Select likeDislike_likes 
from forumLikeDislike 
WHERE topic_id = the topicId variable you submit
```

with this query:

```
select count(*) likes
from forumLikeDislike 
WHERE topic_id = the topicId variable you submit
```

It will return one row with the answer you want.

Comment: So you do not need the array list?

Comment: Not with only one value you don't.

Comment: @DanBarcuk It said missing operator in count(*) likes

Comment: Hello? I am in urgent. Can you please reply?

Comment: I generally find it best to write the sql outside the application first in order to sort out any syntax issues.  That means directly against the database using whatever client you have for that type of db.  For example, I use Management Studio for sql server, sqldeveloper for oracle, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a 100% certain about these points because I haven't tried out the code, but here are my thoughts to get you checking some of this code:

1. Getting the data

   `ArrayList <Integer> likeArray = new ArrayList <Integer>();`
   `for (int count = 0; count < likeArray.size();count++)`

Your likeArray size always starts at zero.  So, it would imply that count is already less then 0, as such I would assume it's not even going into the loop... Have you checked that?

1. Why do you do this:

   ```
   int count = 0;
   int newCount = count + 1;
   eForumLikeDislike amount = new eForumLikeDislike(userName,topicId,newCount);
   amount.likeCounter();
   ```

Your newCount will always be 1.  You can either avoid the count = 0; newCount = count + 1 and just have directly one line that says

```
    eForumLikeDislike amount = new eForumLikeDislike(userName,topicId, 1);
```

or maybe you should be getting the eForumLikeDislike and then have an addLike() method that increments it by 1 with the username and topicId.

Hope that helps.
Cheers

Comment: 1. Ya. But I get the data from database and store it into a variable. After tat I user the variable to sum up with the total of arrayList. 2. Thank you. I thought of that too just now.

Comment: I modified my codes already. I realized that I never add items into arrayList. But it still returning 0

Comment: Hello? I am in urgent. Can you please reply?